# How may I align the following mathematical statement 'horizontally'?

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I appreciate if someone could provide me an answer with coherence.

```
      \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
      \usepackage{blindtext}
      \usepackage{mathtools}
      \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
 \begin{document}
  \textbf{Theorem 1.3.1.} (Multiplication theorem for determinants)
  \textit{Let 
  \begin{flalign*} 
   A=
   \begin{vmatrix}
   a_{ij}
   \end{vmatrix}_n
   \end{flalign*} and
   \begin{flalign*} 
    B=
    \begin{vmatrix}
     b_{ij}
    \end{vmatrix}_n
    \end{flalign*} be given determinants, and write
    \begin{flalign*}
    C=
    \begin{vmatrix}
    c_{ij}
    \end{vmatrix}_n
    \end{flalign*}, where
    \begin{flalign*}
     c_{rs}=
     \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ri}b_{is} 
     \end{flalign*}}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do: use a real theorem structure, with the `amstheorem` or `ntheorem` package, and *not* align, using a `gather*` environment instead. There's no reason to align whatever in such a context.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsthm, mathtools}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}

\begin{thm}[Multiplication theorem for determinants]
Let
\begin{gather*}
A= \begin{vmatrix}
a_{ij}
\end{vmatrix}_n
\quad\text{and}\quad
B=
\begin{vmatrix}
b_{ij}
\end{vmatrix}_n
\intertext{be given determinants, and write}
C =
\begin{vmatrix}
c_{ij}
\end{vmatrix}_n,
\quad\text{where}\quad
c_{rs} =
\smash[t]{∑_{i=1}ⁿ}a_{ri}b_{is}.
\end{gather*}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To Bernard, 
I was quite unaware of gather* environment. Thank you so very much! I could display my theorem as the former.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "horizontal" alignment, you mean that the four `=` symbols should appear "stacked". You can use the `align*` environment along with `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` statements to achieve this objective.

I would also suggest you create a theorem-related environment for the theorem-related material; doing so will make a lot of visual formatting unnecessary, will free you from having to supply the theorems' numbers by hand, and will also let you create easy cross-references to important results.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{thm}{subsection}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}    % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{3} % just for this example
\begin{thm}[Multiplication theorem for determinants]
\label{thm:mult}
Let 
\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{vmatrix} a_{ij} \end{vmatrix}_n
\shortintertext{and}
B &= \begin{vmatrix} b_{ij} \end{vmatrix}_n
\intertext{be given determinants, and write}
C &= \begin{vmatrix} c_{ij} \end{vmatrix}_n \,,
\shortintertext{where}
c_{rs} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ri}b_{is} \,.
\end{align*}
\end{thm}

As established by Theorem \ref{thm:mult}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I shall be so grateful to you for providing me a coherent answer.
Since I just started to learn LaTex, I did not know some commands. Thank you very much!

Comment: The third upvote on this answer put me over the 90K points mark. Many thanks everyone, this is a great site!!